# How to use if statement when function returns 2 arguments?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I recently created a function that checks if a pair exists in my swap smart contract.

The functoin looks like this:

```
function checkIfPairExists(address _token1, address _token2) internal returns(uint, bool) {
    for (uint index = 0; index < tokenPairs.length; index++) {
        if (tokenPairs[index].token1 == _token1 && tokenPairs[index].token2 == _token2) {
            return (index, true);
        }
        else if (tokenPairs[index].token2 == _token1 && tokenPairs[index].token1 == _token2) {
            return (index, true);
        } else {
            return (0, false);
        }
    }

}
```

This function works fine but then when I try to use the function in an if statement like this:

```
if (checkIfPairExists(_token1, _token2) == (uint256, true))
```

How do I write it so it is correct? I am trying to receive index of the pair for my array and bool to see if the pair exists. I then need to save that index to find which pair it should add to.

Hope it makes sense.

Let me know if I should rephrase the question so more people will understand it and it can help them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the returned values to two separate variables. Then you can validate either of them.

```
(uint256 index, bool exists) = checkIfPairExists(_token1, _token2);
if (exists == true) {
    // do something with `index`
}
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the above answer by @pert-hejda, you will need to assign the function return values then you can use those to check the condition. Why? Because multiple returns are represented as [tuples](https://solidity-kr.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/control-structures.html#:%7E:text=Assignment-,Destructuring%20Assignments%20and%20Returning%20Multiple%20Values,values%20at%20the%20same%20time.) and currently the feature you want is not supported in [solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/8919). So, you will need to [assign the return values and use those values in conditionals](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55013/return-multiple-value-from-the-function-read-the-multiple-returns-solidity). Thank you.